# How can I make <div>'s inside a template show or hide depending on a button mouseover?

Tags: angularjs

My directive contains this template:

```
return {
    require: 'ngModel',
    replace: true,
    scope: {
        ngModel: '=',
        pid: '=pid'
    },
    template: '<div class="pagedown-bootstrap-editor"></div>',
    link: function (scope, iElement, attrs, ngModel) {

        var newElement = $compile(
            '<div>' +
               '<div class="wmd-panel">' +
                  '<div id="wmd-button-bar-' + editorUniqueId + '"></div>' +
                  '<textarea data-ng-hide="modal.showPreview == true" class="wmd-input" id="wmd-input-' + editorUniqueId + '">' +
                  '</textarea>' +
               '</div>' +
               '<div data-ng-show="modal.showPreview == true" id="wmd-preview-' + editorUniqueId + '" class="pagedown-preview wmd-panel wmd-preview"></div>' +
            '</div>')(scope);
```

On the same page I have a button like this:

```
<button data-ng-mouseover="modal.showPreview = true">Preview</button>
{{ modal.showPreview }}
```

I added to the template: `data-ng-hide="modal.showPreview == true"` and `data-ng-show="modal.showPreview == true"`

When I hover over the button I can see the value of modal.showPreview changes to True. However nothing happens to the divs that are in the template. How can I make it so that the divs in my template recognize my hovering over the `<button>`?

Comment: Show your directive definition. Most probably you would be creating a isolated scope which cannot access parent scope variables.

Comment: @Chandermani     I updated the question to show this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you don't need [ngModelController](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive:ngModel.NgModelController), it has different purpose. It is mainly use to update the model from your directive.

> The controller contains services for data-binding, validation, CSS updates, and value formatting and parsing. It purposefully does not contain any logic which deals with DOM rendering or listening to DOM events. Such DOM related logic should be provided by other directives which make use of NgModelController for data-binding.

See [**this plunker**](http://plnkr.co/edit/JFgy8JG0nMXegwsimDR5?p=preview) where i create two example for `inherited scope` and `isolated scope`. In your directive if you use

```
scope:{
    modal: '=myDirectiveWithconfig'
  }
```

it creates `isolated scope`. For `isolated scope` you should define `modal.showPreview` in your controller and tell the directive `<div my-directive-withconfig='modal'></div>` to use this value.

For `inherited scope` you don't need to tell the directive `<div my-directive></div>` it'll get the matches value.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to re-bind your onclick event after the template content has been injected

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by this? The button area is in a different part of the page below the template. How can I re-bind the on mouseover?

Comment: I think I may have mis-read your question - as the button is not part of the template the event bound to it should still work after the template is injected

Answer (score 0):

Since you are creating isolated scope add a variable on the isolated scope to track `showPreview`

```
  scope: {
        ngModel: '=',
        pid: '=pid'
        showPreview:'='
    },
```

In your directive usage do something like

```
<my-directive show-preview='modal.showPreview' ...></my-directive>
```